# Editing Code to Work Based on the actual Cell References in my Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, 1) "2 - Staff Listing" and 2) "X - Template".

In the "2 - Staff Listing" sheet there is a column of names in column D starting on Row 9 which I need to replicate over to the "X - Template" sheet.

In the "X - Template" sheet there there is a drop-down menu in cell C2 which can read 1 Week or 5 Week. Depending on what that drop-down says is the number of times each staff members name from "2 - Staff Listing" need to be repeated. So, if it was 5 Week then I would want a column with each staff's name listed 5 times once in each row.

A very nice user helped me with some code to achieve this. However, it was setup to work assuming that the Staff names started in in Cell A1 and should be placed in column A of the "X - Template" sheet. However, in the actual excel file I am working in the Staff names are in column D starting on Row 9 and I need them to appear in the "X - Template" sheet starting in cell B6.

I tried editing the cell references in the code to match the actual excel file. However, now the code run, as in no errors are given, but it doesn't actually do anything. I have put my edited version of the code below. If someone could help me figure out what exactly I have messed up I would really appreciate it!

```
Sub populate_Template()
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim repetition As Long
Dim lr As Long

Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("2 - Staff Listing")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    
    arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 1))
End With

With Sheets("X - Template")
    repetition = Split(.Cells(2, 3).Value, " ")(0)
End With

Dim newarr() As String
ReDim newarr(1 To lr * repetition, 1 To 1)

With Sheets("X - Template")
    count = 0
    For i = 1 To lr
        For y = 1 To repetition
            count = count + 1
            newarr(count, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        Next y
    Next i
    .Range(.Cells(6, 2), .Cells(count, 1)).Value = newarr
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 1))` to read `arr = .Range("D9").Resize(lr - .Range("D9").Row, 1).Value`.  After that, it's easier to change your "anchor" cell from "D9" to someplace else -- just edit and replace the "D9" with the new cell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 1))` this is still looking at Column A. I think you meant for this to be looking at Column D and starting at Row 9. `arr = .Range(.Cells(9, 4), .Cells(lr, 4))`

And then the new array needs to have its size corrected. It also assumes its size as if you're starting from row 1.  `ReDim newarr(1 To lr * repetition, 1 To 1)` changes to `ReDim newarr(1 To (lr - 9 + 1) * repetition, 1 To 1)`.

Finally, the the loop. Its always a better structure to have the loop based explicitly off of the array dimensions. Use `LBound` & `UBound` to ensure your loop never runs out of bounds.

```vb
    count = 0
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For y = 1 To repetition
            count = count + 1
            newarr(count, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        Next y
    Next i
```

For the output, its also a better idea to have the range sizing based on the array dimensions explicitly, rather than implicitly guessing the arrays size based on `count`.

Here is my revision of your code:

```vb
Sub populate_Template()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim repetition As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    With Sheets("2 - Staff Listing")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        
        arr = .Range(.Cells(9, 4), .Cells(lr, 4))
    End With
    
    With Sheets("X - Template")
        repetition = Split(.Cells(2, 3).Value, " ")(0)
    End With
    
    Dim newarr() As String
    ReDim newarr(1 To (lr - 9 + 1) * repetition, 1 To 1)
    
    With Sheets("X - Template")
        count = 0
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            For y = 1 To repetition
                count = count + 1
                newarr(count, 1) = arr(i, 1)
            Next y
        Next i
        .Cells(6, 2).Resize(UBound(newarr) - LBound(newarr) + 1).Value = newarr
    End With
End Sub
```

To make the code more editable in the future, I suggest declaring "D9","C2", and "B6" as variables, and then use the properties of those variables ( like `.Row` and `.Column`) in the code, rather than literal values like "9" and "4".

Here's another version of the code that implements this idea:

```vb
Sub populate_Template()
    
    Dim SourceData As Range
    Set SourceData = Sheets("2 - Staff Listing").Range("D9")
    
    Dim RepititionCell As Range
    Set RepititionCell = Sheets("X - Template").Range("C2")
    
    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = Sheets("X - Template").Range("B6")
    
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    With SourceData.Parent
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, SourceData.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        
        arr = .Range(SourceData, .Cells(lr, SourceData.Column)).Value
    End With
    
    Dim repetition As Long
    repetition = Split(RepititionCell.Value, " ")(0)

    Dim newarr() As String
    ReDim newarr(1 To (lr - SourceData.Row + 1) * repetition, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim count As Long
    count = 0
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Dim y As Long
        For y = 1 To repetition
            count = count + 1
            newarr(count, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        Next y
    Next i
    
    Destination.Resize(UBound(newarr) - LBound(newarr) + 1).Value = newarr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much I just got into work and will try implementing this! Really appreciate the help!!!

Comment: Hey, one more question if you have a second today. I have gotten it working and I added in a if statement for whether it was 5 weeks or 5 weeks AM/PM in which case it doubles the amount of repetitions to 10. The last thing I would like to do is actually have it fill in the week numbers in column C next to the names and then have AM/PM fill in Column D if it is AM/PM or just hide column D if it is not. I think the AM/PM seems simple enough but I am not sure of how to have it cycle through the weeks based on the key cell and double each week if it is AM/PM. Would you be able to help?

Comment: @Brendon You should post that as a new question and provide details about the problem you are encountering in your project. I will take a look when I have time today.

Comment: here is the link to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111880/adding-the-last-few-features-to-my-scheduling-template-generator I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Brendon Make some attempt to implement the features that you are talking about. Don't worry about the quality or even syntax. Just write out the rough sketch of those features in the VBA code. You will get a lot more attention and answers if it looks like you're trying to do it yourself.